# Limit homepage posts to one category and maintian sticky order and pagaintion

Tags: wordpress, pagination, categories, sticky

I have a WordPress homepage. It lists all posts from all categories. This is the WP default behavior.

How do I make it so only those posts shown in the "News" category are shown

The below code is the popular code floating around the net. It works by restricting the category, but then it **breaks the behavior of sticky posts** (they don't float to the top of the post order), **and pagination** (it repeats them on the following page). It is **also inefficient**, because it has to re-query the home page category (the most popular page on a site).

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) {
    query_posts( 'cat=2' ); // This is the category 'News'.
}
?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
Post codes....
```

So, what's the best way to do this? It seems that a high-level filter is the proper way to do this. Any WordPress guru's know the answer to this?

Thanks!
Drew

Comment: It seems that this is a bug in WP, you can find the solution to you problem here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/87472/17187

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the pre_get_pots filter:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

```
function my_before_query( $query ) {

   if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_home() ){
       $query->set('cat', 2); 

   }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_before_query', 1 );
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I wanted! Nice, simple and efficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the pagination thing, and this doesn't address your performance concern either, but here is a workaround I came up with a few years ago regarding the sticky posts issue.

You basically run two queries, with the sticky posts stacked on top of the non-sticky posts. Below is a simplified version of the original code, so I haven't tested this exact code. The general principle is there however. If you want I can post the original implementation (it was a homepage widget).

```
<ul>
    <?php

    $args_sticky = array(
        'cat' => 2,
        'post__in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
    );

    /*
     *STICKY POSTS
     */
    //Display the sticky posts next

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args_sticky );

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    /*
     *NON-STICKY POSTS
     */
    //Display the non-sticky posts next

    $args = array(
       'cat' => 2,
       'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

?>
</ul>
```

For more info see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

I think you may almost have it with your original code, but I'm not sure if the original query_string is automatically appended:

```
<?php
    global $query_string;

    if ( is_home() ) {
        query_posts( $query_string . '&cat=2' );
    }
?>
```

I am a fan of the solution @Simalam proposed. It will result in cleaner template code.